# After updating an entity that has Lazy Loaded attributes JOIN FETCH has no effect

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, lazy-loading, openjpa

We have an entities like this:

```
public User {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", insertable = true, updatable = true)
    @ElementDependent
    private List<Item_x> item_x_list = new ArrayList<Item_x>();
}

public Item_x {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", insertable = true, updatable = true)
    @Element(name = "user_id", required = false)
    private Users user;
}
```

Whenever I add/remove items to User.item_x_list and then persist the User entity using em.merge(User.INSTANCE) the Item_x.user property is NULL.

I am loading the Item_x.user property with a JOIN FETCH query to make sure the attribute is loaded (when I need it). However: the Item_x.user property is NULL even with FETCH JOIN if you have performed a merge on the User Entity.

I tried to workaround by refreshing the Item_x.INSTANCE
but when I call:

```
em.refresh(Item_x.Instance);
```

=> user is null.

Looking in the database I of course can see that the user is NOT null in the Item_x.

How can I force OpenJPA to correctly load the user in Item_x ?
Why is OpenJPA not filling correctly the Item_x.user property / ignores the JOIN FETCH statement?

Comment: Eager loading? The user is only fetched if it is needed - that's the point of lazy, I guess.

Comment: Yes but the thing is that after an update of the entity "Item_x" the user attribute of Item_x (that I previously forced fetching with a JOIN FETCH query) is empty again. That is the problem. I and see no solution in em.refresh(Item_x.Instance); as it will return the same entity, still with Item_x.user = NULL. Also rerunning FETCH JOIN does not fill the user too. So how can I force the entity to load Item_x.user ?

Comment: Try to reword your question. You're omitting too many details to allow someone to have a chance at answering your question.

Comment: @Rick: I have just done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you've created two uni-directional relationships instead of a bi-directional relationship.  One of your classes needs to define a mappedBy relation to the other class, which defines the other class as the "owner" of the relationship.  For example, you can change your example above to define Item_x as the owner as follows:

```
public User {
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Item_x.class, mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @ElementDependent
    private List<Item_x> item_x_list = new ArrayList<Item_x>();
}

public Item_x {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", insertable = true, updatable = true)
    @Element(name = "user_id", required = false)
    private Users user;
}
```

More information is available in the [OpenJPA documentation](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.3/apache-openjpa-1.0.3/docs/manual/jpa_overview_meta_field.html#jpa_overview_meta_mappedby), but they're missing examples which would make it more clear.

Comment: When I add mappedBy as suggested the effect is: When I add a new entry Item_x to the List in User.item_x_list and then call em.merge(User.INSTANCE) the produced record in the database in the Item_x table has a column user with value NULL.

Comment: Try removing the @Element annotation; I left it there because you had it, but I don't think it should actually be there.

Comment: the @Element annotation is from XML serialization: org.simpleframework.xml.Element => this should have not influence on openJPA's persistence strategy.